# Visual Studio Code: Installation hook for snippets extension

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I'd like to publish a Visual Studio Code extension with some JavaScript snippets, but, I'd like to let the user opt into one option, versus another.  Specifically, I'd like to have two sets of snippets, one which produce JavaScript modules with exports formatted like this

```
export default class C { }
```

and another formatted like this

```
class C { 
}

export default C;
```

and I'd like to load the one, or other set of snippets based on the user's preference.

Is there any way at all to support something like this?  In other words, when I publish my extension in the marketplace, is there any hook at all I can expose which would let the user indicate to me which formatting they prefer, so I can load *those* snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that an extension can contribute dynamic snippets through a json file, but your extension could use a custom `CompletionItemProvider` that returns snippets dynamically, something like this perhaps:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode'

class MySnippetProvider extends vscode.CompletionItemProvider {
    public provideCompletionItems(
        _document: vscode.TextDocument,
        _position: vscode.Position,
        _token: vscode.CancellationToken
    ): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.CompletionItem[]> {
        const item = new vscode.CompletionItem('export snippet', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet)

        const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myExtension')
        if (config.get('option', false)) {
            item.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('export default class C { $0 }')
        } else {
            item.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString(
`class C {
    $0
}

export default C;`)
        }


        return [item]
    }

    public resolveCompletionItem(
        item: vscode.CompletionItem,
        _token: vscode.CancellationToken
    ) {
        return item
    }
}
```